# Mod_rewrite http->https redirect EXCEPT one URL

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

OK, so I'm trying to do this:

- !www -> www
- http -> https
  EXCEPT
  /[a-f0-9]{11}/
- https://www.domain.com/[a-f0-9]{11}/ -> http://www.domain.com/[a-f0-9]{11}/
- map to controller: index.php?(uri)
  e.g. /controller/action/id -> index.php/controller/action/id

Summary: all URLs should be https://www.domain.com/(.*) except /[a-f0-9]{11}/, which should be forced to http only.

I have an old set of rules (see below) which don't look very clean.
I've tried adding to them to account for /[a-f0-9]{11} and it ends up redirecting instead of remapping, so I end up with www.domain.com/index.php/thepattern0

How do I clean these rules up and make this work?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    #redirect to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    #redirect to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    #hide index.php
    RedirectMatch 404 .*php\.ini
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+[a-f0-9]{11}[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]

#redirect to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[a-f0-9]{11}[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]

#hide index.php
RewriteRule \.(?:php|ini)$ [L,R=404,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Did what you suggested (fixing the typo on line 15 [om->on])

curl -v -I http://www.domain.com/abc123abc15
[...]
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Tue, 09 Feb 2016 08:09:37 GMT
Date: Tue, 09 Feb 2016 08:09:37 GMT
< Server: Apache
Server: Apache
< Location: https://www.domain.com/abc123abc15

Comment: Trailing slash was the issue. Check updated answer which makes it optional.