# Redirect to HTTPS except a series of URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, apache2

I need to put off the https on a series of urls...

Right now I got this:
https://sub.domain.com/release/download/{id}

I need that all /release/download/{id} urls to be redirected to http

I tried several solutions from here:
[Mod_rewrite http->https redirect EXCEPT one URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285880/mod-rewrite-http-https-redirect-except-one-url)

but none worked.

I got this in my apache conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: IMO this is a bad practice. Connection should always be made secure if possible, especially when you have a HTTPS certificate with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following RewriteRule

```
RewriteEngine On
#redirect http to https except "/release/download/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/release/download/.*
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```